# Angular6 entry component on lazy loaded feature module

Tags: angular6, angular-module

Is possible declare entry components on lazy loaded feature module ? 
I get such an error like this:

```
ERROR Error: No component factory found for NewMessageModalComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
```

This is my feature module :

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    NewMessageModalComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    MessagesRoutingModule
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    NewMessageModalComponent
  ]
})
export class MessagesModule {

}
```

root AppModule

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

root RoutingModule

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
      path: 'messages',
      loadChildren: './messages/messages.module#MessagesModule',
    }
  ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule {

}
```

I know , this works when I declare entry components on AppModule, but why not working on feature module ?

Comment: See github discussion https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14324

Comment: Placing the "missing" component in the `entryComponents` array of the top-most module in the lazy-loaded module group worked for me. While embedded in simultaneously loaded child modules, it was not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be not currently supported and the issue is tagged as a "feature".

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14324#issuecomment-433389833

> Proposed solution: Even though this goes against the modular design
>   adopted by Angular itself, I think that the complexity provided to
>   create dynamic components could be softened by simply appending the
>   LazyModule's entryComponents to the RootInjector's entryComponents and
>   to avoid flooding the RootInjector, whenever you navigate out (which
>   destroys the LazyModule), the previously injected entryComponents
>   would be erased from the array.